# Arithmetic progressions in subset

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, arithmetic

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Does there exist a good algorithm to find a partition of $S$ into "reasonably long" arithmetic progressions?

Many thanks!

Comment: If $n$ is odd, take the partition $\{1,3,5,\ldots,n\}$ and $\{2,4,6,\ldots,n-1\}$, and if $n$ is even, switch the roles of $n$ and $n-1$. I write this to illustrate that your question is difficult to understand, because this is probably not what you are after. Can you give a more precise description in your post of what you are aiming for?

Comment: Even $\{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n\}$ is an arithmetic progression... it is probably the longest one you'll find.  Granted it isn't a partition of $S$ into "progressions", just a single arithmetic progression.

Comment: one wants to partition $S$, not $\{1,\dots,n\}$: you are given $S$, can you write $S$ as a union of "few" arithmetic progressions contained in $S$? I make an example: consider $S=\{1,2,3,4,6,8,10,17\}\subseteq \{1,\dots,17\}$, one can write $S$ as union of $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,6,8,10\}$ and $\{17\}$. Of course the least number would be great, but I guess that is complicated.